# Problem installing python mathutils on windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I used the mathutils module for a project on Linux and wanted to run the project on windows. Problem is I get this error when trying to install the mathutils module on windows :

(python version : 3.9.1)

```
(venv) $> python -m pip install mathutils 
Collecting mathutils
  Using cached mathutils-2.81.2.tar.gz (226 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for mathutils, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mathutils
    Running setup.py install for mathutils ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Local Chaire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z_trq8af\\mathutils_c4fe624347df421aa50eee4591602a93\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Local Chaire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z_trq8af\\mathutils_c4fe624347df421aa50eee4591602a93\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Local Chaire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xz07h_nz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include\site\python3.9\mathutils'
         cwd: C:\Users\Local Chaire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z_trq8af\mathutils_c4fe624347df421aa50eee4591602a93\
    Complete output (113 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'mathutils' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\blenlib
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\blenlib\intern
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\generic
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\mathutils
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\stubs
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/blenlib/intern/math_base.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/blenlib/intern/math_base.obj /J
    math_base.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/blenlib/intern/math_color.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/blenlib/intern/math_color.obj /J
    math_color.c
    src/blenlib/intern/math_color.c(206): warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   
    src/blenlib/intern/math_color.c(209): warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/blenlib/intern/math_geom.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/blenlib/intern/math_geom.obj /J
    math_geom.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/blenlib/intern/math_matrix.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/blenlib/intern/math_matrix.obj /J
    math_matrix.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/blenlib/intern/math_rotation.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/blenlib/intern/math_rotation.obj /J
    math_rotation.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/blenlib/intern/math_vector.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/blenlib/intern/math_vector.obj /J
    math_vector.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/generic/py_capi_utils.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/generic/py_capi_utils.obj /J
    py_capi_utils.c
    src/generic/py_capi_utils.c(89): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/generic/py_capi_utils.c(202): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
    src/generic/py_capi_utils.c(213): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/mathutils/mathutils.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/mathutils/mathutils.obj /J
    mathutils.c
    src/mathutils/mathutils.c(75): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils.c(179): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils.c(265): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils.c(306): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils.c(343): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils.c(382): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils.c(427): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.obj /J
    mathutils_Color.c
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(247): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(348): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(361): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(361): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(385): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(395): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(395): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(567): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(572): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(605): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(632): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(660): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Color.c(771): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.obj /J
    mathutils_Euler.c
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(458): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(559): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(572): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(572): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(596): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(606): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(606): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(682): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'short' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(829): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'const short' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Euler.c(851): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'const short' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMATH_STANDALONE -DWITH_ASSERT_ABORT -Isrc/stubs -Isrc/blenlib -Isrc/makesdna -IC:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.obj /J
    mathutils_Matrix.c
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(45): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'matrix_func'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(45): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'matrix_func'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(45): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(45): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(45): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(367): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'const unsigned short', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(373): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'const unsigned short', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(398): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'matrix_func'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(398): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'matrix_func'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(398): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(398): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(398): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(519): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(549): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'double' to 'const float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(552): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'double' to 'const float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(556): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'double' to 'const float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(910): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'const float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1714): warning C4013: 'matrix__apply_to_copy' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1714): error C2065: 'PyNoArgsFunction': undeclared identifier
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1714): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'Matrix_adjugate'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1714): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1922): error C2065: 'PyNoArgsFunction': undeclared identifier
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1922): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'Matrix_transpose'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1922): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1968): error C2065: 'PyNoArgsFunction': undeclared identifier
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1968): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'Matrix_normalize'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(1968): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2518): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2524): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2577): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2755): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2768): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2768): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2792): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2802): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(2802): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(3441): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(3447): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(3462): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(3462): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(3490): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/mathutils/mathutils_Matrix.c(3496): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Local Chaire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z_trq8af\\mathutils_c4fe624347df421aa50eee4591602a93\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Local Chaire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z_trq8af\\mathutils_c4fe624347df421aa50eee4591602a93\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Local Chaire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xz07h_nz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Local Chaire\Documents\repos\crane_data_analysis\webapp\venv\include\site\python3.9\mathutils' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm using VS Code but I have VS2019 installed with the desktop c++ build tools so I don't really understand what's missing for it to build.

UPDATE:

As suggested by one of the answers, I tried building from source directly but the result is the same.

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: my current version is 3.9.1

Comment: For the record, I also have the same problem with mathutils-2.81.2 on Python 3.9.7, VS 2019 16.11.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same errors on Linux with Python 3.9 but I managed to compile it with Python 3.8. The bottom line is: the project is not yet updated for Python 3.9. Please [report](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-mathutils/-/issues) the problem and try Python 3.8.

Comment: thanks a lot, gonna try this and make you know if it really is the problem!

Comment: Just downgraded to python 3.8.3, works perfectly thanks !

Comment: This solved a similar problem I encountered trying to install it on a Mac M1. Python 3.7 won't work for it, 3.9 won't work for it (as you specified) so indeed, only Python 3.8 works to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about install it by source code:

```sh
cd ..
git clone https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-mathutils.git
cd - && cd ../blender-mathutils
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
cd -
```

See more at https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-mathutils

Comment: I have the exact same result, so the problem is really a build problem, which is weird because I have the c++ build tools

Comment: I also wanted to try the build instructions with cmake but it seems it doesn't generates the required makefile because when I run "make" I get a "No targets specified and no makefile found." error

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3.9.2 and the main problem is deprecation of a function (as mentioned in [here](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-mathutils/-/issues/23)). So the solution is similar to @Waket Zheng but apply the patch in the [link](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-mathutils/uploads/aebb580ffe731f0d0b56d9dc7463b5c6/Py39-PyNoArgsFucntion-20210809.patch). Steps:

```
cd ..
git clone https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-mathutils.git
cd - && cd ../blender-mathutils
git apply {directory_of_patch}/Py39-PyNoArgsFucntion-20210809.patch
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```